# C# Easier way to create array of pictureboxes (48x boxes)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, picturebox

Project enviroment: Visual Studio 2013, using Windows Forms template.

This is what I currently have, I assume there is an easier way to create an array like this. I have tried many ways, but I do not know C# well enough yet.

```
   PictureBox[] boxes = {
                 runeBox1, runeBox2, runeBox3, runeBox4, runeBox5, runeBox6, runeBox7, runeBox8, 
                 runeBox9, runeBox10, runeBox11, runeBox12, runeBox13, runeBox14, runeBox15, runeBox16, 
                 runeBox17, runeBox18, runeBox19, runeBox20, runeBox21, runeBox22, runeBox23, runeBox24, 
                 runeBox25, runeBox26, runeBox27, runeBox28, runeBox29, runeBox30, runeBox31, runeBox32, 
                 runeBox33, runeBox34, runeBox35, runeBox36, runeBox37, runeBox38, runeBox39, runeBox40, 
                 runeBox41, runeBox42, runeBox43, runeBox44, runeBox45, runeBox46, runeBox47, runeBox48};
```

What I have tried so far is this:

```
string[] strArr = new string[48];
        for (int i = 1; i != 48; i++)
            {
            strArr[i] = "runebox" + i.ToString();
            }
        int count = 0;
        foreach (object p in this.Controls)
            {
            if (p.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
                {
                if (((PictureBox)p).Name == strArr[count])
                    {
                    boxes[count] = ((PictureBox)p);
                    count++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This compiles, but it gives a nullpointer exception in the array boxes.

I have also attempted a typeconverter, but this gave me no results as well.

Hopefully some of you clever ones can tell me the road to Rome.

Comment: 48 Picture boxes? I'm sure you're doing it wrong. Before fixing the `NullReferenceException` you need to address that ~48 picture boxes.

Comment: You fill your strArr starting with index 1 but when you access the Controls of your Form you start with count = 0... I suggest you change your for-loop to (int i = 0; i < 48; i++).

Comment: It would help to know why you are doing it in the first place.  An array of PictureBox controls when it appears these already exist on the form?  Why not just access them directly, then?  Why the array at all?

Comment: I have placed 48 boxes, that I fill with an image.
I need the array in order to clear out the images easily, so that the program can place new images there again without displaying the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to find all pictureBoxes on form in one sentence

```
private PictureBox[] boxes;
.ctor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    boxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
            .Where(pb => pb.Name.StartsWith("runeBox"))
            .OrderBy(pb => int.Parse(pb.Name.Replace("runeBox","")))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Now I just need to learn how to come up with these things myself. YAY LEARNING!

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to create it and later manually add them to the form you can use LINQ and Enumerables to your advantage

you can create them like so :

```
var pictureboxes = Enumerable.Range(1,48).ToList().Select(i=> new PictureBox(){Name = "runebox" + i.ToString()}).ToList();
```

then to add to the form you can simply do :

```
pictureboxes.ForEach(pic=> this.Controls.Add(pic));
```